# If else condition works with days?

Tags: r, date, if-statement, rstudio, lubridate

I required date as mentioned below in if condition.

**if day('2019-12-23') <=15 then '2019-11-16' else '2019-12-01'**.

I have tried writing codes in R, but output is not correct.

**Codes**

```
ifelse(day(Sys.Date()) <=15,
  (ymd(Sys.Date()-day(Sys.Date()-1)) %m-% months(1))+15,
  ymd(Sys.Date()-day(Sys.Date()-1)))
```

**Output**

```
18231
```

**Required Output**

```
2019-12-01
```

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solutions thanks. forgot to convert into character.

updated query

```
ifelse(day(Sys.Date()) <=15,
  as.character((ymd(Sys.Date()-(day(Sys.Date()-1))) %m-% months(1))+15),
  as.character(ymd(Sys.Date()-(day(Sys.Date()-1)))))
```